# How to apply transformation constraint on objects having different orientation?

Tags: constraints, transform-orientation

I want to rotate wheel having its own custom orientation. When I apply transformation constraint, that wheel rotates according to global orientation but I want it in custom. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: I suspect you're misunderstanding what the object's local axes are-- they are not the directions that the object moves when you translate it in local orientation!  I recommend parenting to bones with bone constraints instead of direct object constraints, as the local axes are more obvious with bones, and armature/bones provide additional benefits.

Comment: I have given constraints using empy cube. I have uploded video of my problem on drive. This is the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/16N2vbWU1983sR_FXfIYg8XoHBjazcW0h/view?usp=sharing